# Electrostatic force on electron, oscillation with angular frequency $\omega$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, electrons, coulombs-law

An electron is constrained to the central axis of the charged ring of radius $R$, as shown in Fig. 22-11 below, with $z$ much less than $R$.

Show that the electrostatic force on the electron can cause it to oscillate through the ring center with an angular frequency
$$ \omega = \sqrt{\frac{e q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 m R^3}} $$
where $q$ is the ring’s charge and $m$ is the electron’s mass.

[image: figure 22-11]

Comment: usually, people like to see your attempt for homework questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the electrostatic force of the ring on the electron. The picture suggests that you calculate the electric field due to a small segment of the ring. The charge of that small segment is $\displaystyle{dq=\frac{ds}{2\pi R}q}$.

You should write the distance between $dq$ charge and the electron in terms of $R$ and $z$. The electric field due to this small charge has a component along the ring axis $dE\cos\theta$ as well as a component perpendicular to the axis. Due to symmetry of the charge $q$, the perpendicular components cancel.

So all you need to do is sum up the components along the axis. You will need to write $\cos\theta$ in terms of $z$ and $R$. You now have the force on the electron. In the small $z$ limit, you can approximate this force as $F=-k z$, which is equivalent to he force of a spring. Then the oscillation angular frequency is $\displaystyle{\omega=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}}$

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the electric field a distance z from the origin. in doing so only calculate the z-component of electric field because the horizontal component cancels. Next obtain the force on the electron due to this field.
In the denominator you get (R squared + z squared) to the power 3/2. and z in the numerator. 
For electron near the origin on the z-axis z << R and z can be neglected. 
This gives a force on electron near the origin on the z-axis as constant x z/R3 that is R cube.
Since omega squared is return force per unit displacement per unit mass. You get the answer.

Answer (score -3):

It is just easy no need to confuse or complicate the problem. Here is the method to make it easy.........

Angular frequency is (w)
 Torque= -PE SINx
 As well as we know Torque(T)= Ia.  { inertia×angular acceleration}
Then
Ia= -PESINx   [SINx  is small so it replaced by x ]
a=-PEx/I 
a= -PE/I × x
(a= -w^2 x)
Compare
W=√PE/I 
Dipole--P=2rq  €  {r= radius of circle... 2r=distance between to charges ( it is diameter ;;charges present at opposite sides of diameter)}
E=kq/r^2
Substitute
W=√kq/r^2 × 2rq × 1/mr^2        (mr^2 is inertia of circle(ring))
W=√kq^2/mr^3

Comment: Please format your answer properly